# sed: How do I replace all lines containing a certain string?

Tags: string, sed

Say I have a file containing these lines:

```
tomatoes
bananas
tomatoes with apples
pears
pears with apples
```

How do I replace **every line** containing the word "apples" with just "oranges"? This is what I want to end up with:

```
tomatoes
bananas
oranges
pears
oranges
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `sed 's/.*apples.*/oranges/'` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use awk

```
$ awk '/apples/{$0="orange"}1' file
tomatoes
bananas
orange
pears
orange
```

this says to search for apples, then change the whole record to "orange".